# Is allennlp.service being deprecated?

Tags: allennlp

I noticed that after I pulled version 1.0.0, I was no longer able to import allennlp.service. I see the docs are still updated only as far as 0.9.0 as well so I'm not sure what the status of the service module is.

Comment: What was in the `service` module has moved here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-server. And FYI the updated docs are here: https://docs.allennlp.org/v1.1.0/

Answer (score 2):

Answer in comments above; the functionality was moved to http://github.com/allenai/allennlp-server as a plugin.